# Updating Matrix Safecracker Cell type to File Cell Type

Tags: matrix, channel-form, safecracker-file

I'm doing a major update on a site -- EE v2.1.3 to v2.8.1

I have a Matrix field that's using the safecracker cell type and I'm wondering what's the best to handle this.

Pre-update the channel form field didn't exist and post update I'm not able to access the field to update it without error messages.

Should I edit the database directly and update the col_type from 'safecracker_file' to 'file'?

I'm thinking that if I do this then I can go in through the EE control panel and update the field details, but I'm not sure if there are other ramifications that I'm unaware of.

Appreciate any feedback or insights.

Jules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take backups is the 1st thing to remember.

Past that, I would look at using the original data and converting your safe_cracker field to a simple text input field (not textarea, make sure the field doesn't convert your data - select 'none' in the format section).

Doing this should write the safe_cracker data to your newly converted text input field.

Upgrade the CMS

When complete, select your text input field and set it to 'file' type. This should retain your file data and allow you to now use upload field type hopefully.

Comment: Thanks for the response stuartmcd69! -- I did as you suggested, but instead of spending time reverting back to the older EE version I did updated the database directly, then went into the control panel and updated the cell type to file.  After I updated the template code I tested form submission and all went well.